# Hi everyone. I need a little help on how to do this code. I have a main that I'm not allowed to change, but I have to make it work

Tags: constructor, operator-keyword

this is how my main looks

```
b = 3;
cout << "Affectation OK\n";

const Uint c = 13;
cout << uint64_t(c) << " = 13:  explicit cast to uint64_t\n";
```

this is how my class looks

```
class Uint {
private:
    string nb;
public:

    Uint();
    Uint(size_t a);//Overload constructeur



    operator uint64_t() {
        return static_cast<uint64_t>(123456789UL);
    }


};//LABO21_UINT_H
#endif
```

i tried so many ways to do that, but no succes. If anyone could help me, on how to use the operators on this , it would be a greatp help

Answer (score 0):

The ctor:

```
Uint(size_t a){
  //convert a to string
  nb=...
}
```

If you can't change the main, you should add a friend function:

```
friend operator uint64_t(Uint c) {
        return static_cast<uint64_t>(c.nb);
    }
```

friend function give you the option to access the private fields of class eventhough it's not a member function.